# Urllib Python is not providing with the html code I see with with inspect element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to crawl the results in this link:

url =  "http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F"

When I inspect it with firebug I can see the html code and I know what I need to do to extract the tweets. The problem is when I get the response using urlopen, i don't get the same html code. I only get  tags. What am I missing?

Example code below:

```
   def get_tweets(section_url):
     html = urlopen(section_url).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
     tweets = soup.find("div", "results")
     category_links = [dd.a["href"] for tweet in tweets.findAll("div", "result-tweet")]
     return category_links

url =  "http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F"
cat_links = get_tweets(url)
```

Thanks,
YB

Comment: A JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thank you. This a bit new to me, would you be able to provide with more information? Many thanks.

Comment: JavaScript is a client-side programming language implemented by all common browsers. It can manipulate the HTML returned by the server as well as perform asynchronous requests that allow it to retrieve data without disrupting the current page. Both things have happened here, which means that the HTML directly retrieved from the server does not match the HTML that the browser currently contains.

Comment: Or you could just use [this link](http://otter.topsy.com/trackbacks.js?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F&infonly=0&call_timestamp=1411090809443&apikey=09C43A9B270A470B8EB8F2946A9369F3)

Comment: @Himal how do i find this link for any other pages on this website?

Comment: Use browser's console to see related ajax requests.

Comment: @Himal, thanks for your help. One last question, how can i extract all the answers (not only the first 10 answers?)

Comment: You have to iterate through the list by modifying the `&offset=10` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the content of `results` div is filled up with extra HTTP call and javascript code being executed on the browser side. `urllib` only "sees" the initial HTML page that doesn't contain the data you need.

One option would be to follow @Himal's suggestion and simulate the underlying request to `trackbacks.js` that is sent for the data with tweets. The result is in JSON format that you can [`load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module coming with standard library:

```
import json
import urllib2

url = 'http://otter.topsy.com/trackbacks.js?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F&infonly=0&call_timestamp=1411090809443&apikey=09C43A9B270A470B8EB8F2946A9369F3'
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for tweet in data['response']['list']:
    print tweet['permalink_url']
```

Prints:

```
http://twitter.com/Evonomie/status/512179917610835968
http://twitter.com/abs_office/status/512054653723619329
http://twitter.com/TKE_Global/status/511523709677756416
http://twitter.com/trevinocreativo/status/510216232122200064
http://twitter.com/TomCrouser/status/509730668814028800
http://twitter.com/Evonomie/status/509703168062922753
http://twitter.com/peterchaly/status/509592878491136000
http://twitter.com/chandagarwala/status/509540405411840000
http://twitter.com/Ayjay4650/status/509517948747526144
http://twitter.com/Marketingccc/status/509131671900536832
```

This was "going down to metal" option.

---

Otherwise, you can take a "high-level" approach and don't bother about what is there happening under-the-hood. Let the real browser load the page which you would interact with through [selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # can be Firefox(), PhantomJS() and more
driver.get("http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F")

for tweet in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-tweet'):
    print tweet.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="media-body"]//ul[@class="inline"]/li//a').get_attribute('href')

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
http://twitter.com/Evonomie/status/512179917610835968
http://twitter.com/abs_office/status/512054653723619329
http://twitter.com/TKE_Global/status/511523709677756416
http://twitter.com/trevinocreativo/status/510216232122200064
http://twitter.com/TomCrouser/status/509730668814028800
http://twitter.com/Evonomie/status/509703168062922753
http://twitter.com/peterchaly/status/509592878491136000
http://twitter.com/chandagarwala/status/509540405411840000
http://twitter.com/Ayjay4650/status/509517948747526144
http://twitter.com/Marketingccc/status/509131671900536832
```

---

This is how you can scale the second option to get all of tweets following pagination:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

BASE_URL = 'http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F&offset={offset}'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# get tweets count
driver.get('http://topsy.com/trackback?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F')
tweets_count = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@data-name="all"]/a/span').text)

for x in xrange(0, tweets_count, 10):
    driver.get(BASE_URL.format(offset=x))

    # page header appears in case no more tweets found
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="page-header"]/h3')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        break

    # wait for results
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "results"))
    )

    # get tweets
    for tweet in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-tweet'):
        print tweet.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="media-body"]//ul[@class="inline"]/li//a').get_attribute('href')

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll go through your answer in details and get back to you if i have any questions. Cheers

Comment: I tried both options and they are working, thank you so much. I have 2 questions if possible: 


1) For option1, how do I know what's the link I need to use to get the underlying request? In other words where did "http://otter.topsy.com/trackbacks.js?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2014%2F08%2F27%2Faustralia-retail-evolution-lab-aopen-shopping%2F&infonly=0&call_timestamp=1411090809443&apikey=09C43A9B270A470B8EB8F2946A9369F3" come from?


2) As you can see, the webpage is returning only 10 results. If I want to extract all the results, what should I do? 

Thank you,

Comment: @ybb sure, 1) I've just explored the Network tab in browser (chrome) developer tools. 2) updated the answer. Hope that helps.